# Заменить br на новые строки

Tags: javascript, jquery, регулярные-выражения

Есть текст как на скриншоте, как в нём заменить теги `<br>`, на новые строки ? (\n)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте вот таким регулярным выражением найти `/<br.*?\/?>/g`

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь jQuery методом [`replaceAll`](https://api.jquery.com/replaceAll/). Примерно так:

```
$('\n').replaceAll('.amessage br');
```

Живой пример:

```js
$('button').click(function () {
    console.log('html до:\n\n' + $('.amessage').html());
    $('\n').replaceAll('.amessage br');
    console.log('html после:\n\n' + $('.amessage').html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="amessage">
    строка 1
    <br>
    строка 2
    <br class="br">
    <br>
    строка 3
</div>
<button>Заменить</button>
```

Если же дана строка, содержащая html элементы, и нужно заменить `<br>` в ней, то можно сделать примерно так:

```js
let text =
`<div class="amessage">
    строка 1
    <br>
    строка 2
    <br class="br">
    <br>
    строка 3
</div>`;

function replaceBrTagsToNewLineChar(text) {
  let element = $.parseHTML('<div>' + text + '</div>');
  element = $(element[0]);
  $('\n').replaceAll(element.find('br'));
  return element.html();
}

console.log('html до:\n\n' + text);
console.log('html после:\n\n' + replaceBrTagsToNewLineChar(text));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: а как можно это "вставить в функцию" дело в том что в неё поступает текст для обработки

Comment: @turik97, посмотрите дополнение к ответу.

Answer (score 2):

В принципе, можно попробовать просто оставить только текст:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
  var div = document.querySelector('.amessage')
  div.textContent = div.textContent;
})
```

```css
.amessage {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="amessage">
  строка 1
  <br> строка 2
  <br class="br">
  <br> строка 3
</div>
<button>Заменить</button>
```